# using my if statement to be more precise

Tags: javascript, if-statement

hey guys just a quick question.

i'm still unsure how to use if statements.

researched and explained. all i know is that it searches for that one specific statement that needs to be answered.

anyways i have a while loop running reading through a record.

its asking for a zipcode from user and now i just want it to search through the record and print out only the zipcodes that match the zipcode the user entered.

i'm not getting any errors or printouts of the specific zipcode being searched through the assigned records.

```
    records = openZipCodeStudyRecordSet();




    userEntered = prompt("Search students in current zipcode:");


        while (records.readNextRecord()) {
    // This IF only in place for this particular example program
    // Remove the IF to work with the entire file

    firstName   = records.getSampleFirstName();
    lastName    = records.getSampleLastName();
    gender      = records.getSampleGender();
    zipCode     = records.getSampleZipCode();


    for (counter = 0; counter <records.length; counter++) {
    if(userEntered == records[counter].length){

        zipCode += records[counter];
        }
    }


    allDisplayRows += "<tr><td>" + firstName + "</td>" 
            + "<td>" + lastName + "</td><td>" + gender 
            + "</td><td>" + zipCode + "</td></tr>";

    count++;
}
```

i'm confused to why it wont compare it to the records. is my for loop and if loop correct?

i feel i'm doing this all wrong.

1. ask user for a zip code
2. loop through the records
3. then compare the zipcode entered to the records
4. after doing that store the zipcodes that were found into a record and then print it out.

Answer (score 1):

`records.readNextRecord()` doesn't return the zip code, it just goes to the next record, so it makes no sense to call it inside the loop and compare that with `userEntered`. You should be comparing that with the zip code you get from the record.

```
while (records.readNextRecord()) {
    zipCode = records.getSampleZipCode();
    if (userEntered == zipCode) {
        firstName = records.getSampleFirstName();
        lastName = records.getSampleLastName();
        gender = records.getSampleGender();    
        break;
    }
}

console.log(zipCode, firstName, lastName, gender);
```

If you need to find all the records with the zipcode, you should put the matches in an array, and not use `break`.

```
results = [];
while (records.readNextRecord()) {
    zipCode = records.getSampleZipCode();
    if (userEntered == zipCode) {
        results.push({
            zipCode: zipCode,
            firstName: records.getSampleFirstName(),
            lastName: records.getSampleLastName(),
            gender: records.getSampleGender()
        };
    }
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: i got to that part. fixed it.

now i cant seem to get it to print the zipcode that the user entered.

i tried userEntered = zipCode so that it stores it. but should i put an array behind zipcode? or turn zipcode into an array to be more precise.

Comment: i still cant get the userEntered to == the records in the zip and print out the correct zipcodes. it works but wasn't the correct zipcodes that user entered.

Comment: Do you need to find multiple records with the same zipcode? Your original code has `break`, so I thought you wanted to stop searching as soon as you find a match.

Comment: yeah i do. does the break stop the if statement so it only runs once?

Comment: The break statement stops the `while` loop. What else did you think it was for?

Comment: i thought it broke the if statement. didnt think itd stop the while loop.

i will fix that and post results

Comment: I think you need to go back to your tutorials. It makes no sense to break out of an if statement, since it doesn't continue anywhere.